# Return relations as child nodes in tree (Neo4j Cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Is there a way to retrieve relations as child elements of a tree?

This is the basic data i have:

```
CREATE (:Customer {id:1, name:'Customer 1'})<-[:CREATED_BY]-(c:Category {id:1, name:'Category 1'})
WITH c as category, range(2, 7) as subCatIds
FOREACH (s IN subCatIds | CREATE (category)<-[:SUBCATEGORY_OF]-(:Category {id:s, name:'SubCategory '+s}))
WITH category, range(1, 5) as attTypeIds
FOREACH (a IN attTypeIds | CREATE (category)-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTE {name:'Attribute '+a, required: (a%2=0)}]->(:AttributeType {id:a, name:'AttributeType '+a}))
WITH category
MATCH p = (:AttributeType)<-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]-(category)<-[:SUBCATEGORY_OF]-(:Category)
RETURN p
```

So this query returns correctly the tree structure:

```
MATCH  (:Customer {id:1})<-[:CREATED_BY]-(c:Category {id:1}),
       p = (c)<-[:SUBCATEGORY_OF*0..1]-(:Category)
WITH COLLECT(p) as category
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(category) yield value
RETURN value
```

How do i add the relationships [:HAS_ATTRIBUTE] as child nodes to this query?

I've tried already:

```
MATCH  (:Customer {id:1})<-[:CREATED_BY]-(c:Category {id:1}),
       SubCatsP = (c)<-[:SUBCATEGORY_OF*0..1]-(:Category),
       AttP = (c)-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(att:AttributeType)
WITH COLLECT(SubCatsP) as category, RELATIONSHIPS(AttP) as attributes
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(category) yield value
RETURN value, attributes
```

But this returns 5 records (1 for each relationship [:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]) with the Category-Subcategories tree repeated.

I expect the result to be:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: 'Category 1',
 SUBCATEGORY_OF:[
   {id:2, name: 'Subcategory 2'}, ...
  ]
 HAS_ATTRIBUTE:[
   {name: 'Attribute 1', required: false, att: {name:'AttributeType 5',id:5}}, ...
<OR>
{name: 'Attribute 1', required: false, att.name:'AttributeType 5',att.id:5}, ...
  ]
}
```

Is this even possible or do you consider a better approach to perform 2 separate queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try combining the paths into a single list:

```
MATCH  (:Customer {id:1})<-[:CREATED_BY]-(c:Category {id:1}),
   SubCatsP = (c)<-[:SUBCATEGORY_OF*0..1]-(:Category),
   AttP = (c)-[:HAS_ATTRIBUTE]->(att:AttributeType)
WITH COLLECT(SubCatsP) + COLLECT(AttP) as category
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(category) yield value
RETURN value
```

Comment: Combining paths with + was the answer